# what is the meaning of multiple HSPs under a single hit?

Tags: xml, bioinformatics, hit, blast

I am new to the field of Bioinformatics.  I was looking at a BLAST xml output file and I was trying to understand why there are multiple HSPs under each blast hit. I know HSP stands for High-Scoring Segment Pair but I don't really understand how and why multiple HSPs gets assigned to a single hit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okk, so I am giving you a general idea. For instance, for sequence A and sequence B, multiple portions of the sequence might be identical/similar or high scores. To be more specific:

Sequence A: #######AAAAAA????????ATCG///////////////////////////////

Sequence B: #######CCCCCC????????ATCG///////////////////////////////

So, you will get three results for the above two sequences. One for '#' portions, another for '?' portions, and the last one for '/' portions. Anyway, I am glad that more people are questioning about bioinformatics related stuffs.

Cheers!